# This is your room. You can/are able to use the towel hung on the wall - why does "be able to" sound unnatural here

Tags: meaning

**Example 1**

> This is your room. You can use the towel hung on the wall.

**Example 2**

> This is your room. You are able to use the towel hung on the wall.

**Example 3**

> This word means "how are you." You can use it in your daily life.

**Example 4**

> This word means "how are you." You are able to use it in your daily life.

Many materials say that "be able to" and "can" are interchangeable in most cases.

However, I feel that Example 1 and Example 3 are more natural than Example 2 and Example 4.

I am wondering whether there is a usage of "can" which can not be changed to "be able to."

Comment: (1) means 'That's the towel that we have provided for you' (you are allowed to use it), while (2) would mean 'You are capable of using it'.

Comment: In Portuguese, the verb **poder** (to be able to/capable of) is used to mean **you may/can/go ahead**.  I suspect that it may influence the unnatural use of **you are able to** in English by speakers of Latin languages.

Comment: *It **can** be difficult to understand him, because of his strong accent*. There's no easy way to rephrase that using ***be able to***.

Answer (score 3):

“Can” and “may” have partially overlapping meanings. One of those meanings is “be permitted to.” There is, however, a long standing recommendation on usage to avoid using “can” in that sense. It is by no means a rule of grammar and is not even a majority usage. I admit that I follow that minority usage because distinguishing between permission and ability is frequently clarifying, but it is not a rule.

I think that using “be able” as a synonym for “may” is considerably less prevalent than using “can,” so your feeling about “can” being more natural in your examples seems correct to me, but I **personally** would prefer “may” to “can.”